# Delete JSON object properties with JavaScript in Karate

Tags: json, object, dynamic, properties, karate

How do I delete JSON object properties dynamically? I tried this:

```
* def delKey = 
                    """
                              function(json, key) {
                                delete json[key];
                                return json;
                              }
                    """

* def aJson = { row: null, age: 35 , city: 'na'}
* print "Before: "
* print aJson
* def called = delKey(aJson, 'age')
* print "After: "
* print aJson
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have not seen the `remove` and `set` keywords. Here is the right approach. Also note how the `print` statement supports a comma-delimited style so that it will pretty-print:

```
* def aJson = { row: null, age: 35 , city: 'na' }
* print 'Before: ', aJson
* remove aJson.age
* print 'After: ', aJson
```

If you need to remove keys dynamically, the JS API `karate.remove(name, path)` can be used. Refer to the docs !

EDIT: The JS `delete` is now supported:

```
* def foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }
* delete foo.a
* match foo == { b: 2 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I really _read_ the docs carefully. The `remove` and `set` do not help for my situation, yet `eval karate.remove...` did. Still, the question remains - why the code above does not work?

Comment: @DragomirDraganov thanks, I actually took a closer look. because of the way Karate works, variables are Java `Map` objects within a function block. so just change the second line of your function to `json.remove(key);` and it will work !

Comment: @PeterThomas Can I call this remove under an if condition? The below code is giving me syntax error * if(condition=="true"){remove aJson.age}  >>>> js failed:
01: if(condition=="true"){remove aJson.age}
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:29 Expected ; but found aJson
if(condition=="true"){remove aJson.age}

Comment: @SourabhRoy in the 1.X version try `delete` instead of `remove`. else ask a new question

Comment: Since Karate v1.4.0.RC3 the `delete` approach works only limited (see https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2264 for details).